# Is there a way to get @Scheduled job in Spring to start without starting the application/running the application?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-scheduled, spring-batch-job-monitoring

There is a Batch job that I have annotated with @Scheduled and a Cron expression. When I run the application from my IDE, the scheduled job runs according to the condition provided.
How does the scheduled job work if I do not start or run the app? I want it to run at a specified time every day?

Comment: Without running a job you can't expect the job to run. Your application must be running. Using cron you can decide when to run the job. Some cron expression info from [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to start your application and Spring will be execute the `@Scheduled` method according to the schedule you give.

If you want to run jobs at a specific schedule without having a JVM running continuously, you have to use an external scheduler like [unix's cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for example.

Comment: Thank you. I will look at Unix’s cron.